# Verify if EditText is empty Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm kind of stuck in this condition and don't know what to do.
I need it to return `true` or `false` if users don't insert the value into the `EditText`. Actually the app crashes and closes.

```
campoBNow = findViewById(R.id.txtMenorBNow);
campoLucro = findViewById(R.id.txtLucro);

btnClicou.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Pega o texto do BuyNow e Lucro e coloca nas variáveis de texto.
        String pegaBNow = campoBNow.getText().toString();
        String pegaLucro = campoLucro.getText().toString();
        String item = spNivel.getSelectedItem().toString(); //Atribui o ComboBox para String...

        //Atribui o valor dos textos convertidos pra float nas variáveis float.
        double bNow = Double.parseDouble(pegaBNow);
        double lDes = Double.parseDouble(pegaLucro);

/*
        Condicional de verificação vazio...
*/

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pegaBNow)){
            tv5.setText("DIGITE UM VALOR DE BUY NOW"); //BuyNow vazio, mostra mensagem...
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DIGITE UM VALOR DE BUY NOW", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pegaLucro)){
            tv5.setText("DIGITE UM VALOR DE LUCRO"); //Lucro vazio, mostra mensagem...
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DIGITE UM VALOR DE LUCRO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pegaBNow) && TextUtils.isEmpty(pegaLucro)){
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DIGITE OS VALORES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }else{
            //Atribui o valor dos textos convertidos pra float nas variáveis float.
            double res = ((bNow - (0.05*bNow)) - lDes); //Calcula o resultado...
            if(res < 0){
                tv5.setText("PROPORÇÃO LUCRO E BUY NOW INCORRETO");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PROPORÇÃO INCOMPATÍVEL!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                //Início do IF para o nível da carta...
                if (item == "Ouro") {
                    if (res > 0 && res <= 5000) { //Começar a condicional de comparação de valor.
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É BAIXO");
                    } else if (res > 5000 && res <= 15000) {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É MÉDIO");
                    } else {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É ALTO");
                    }


                } else if (item == "Prata") {
                    if (res > 0 && res <= 2000) {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É BAIXO");
                    } else if (res > 2000 && res <= 5000) {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É MÉDIO");
                    } else {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É ALTO");
                    }

                } else { //else para Bronze.
                    if (res > 0 && res <= 1000) {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É BAIXO");
                    } else if (res > 1000 && res <= 3000) {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É MÉDIO");
                    } else {
                        tv5.setText("O RISCO DO TRADE É ALTO");
                    }

                }
                //Fim do IF para o nível da carta...
            }

            //tv4.setText("COMPRE O JOGADOR POR ATÉ: " + res + " COINS");
            //tv5.setText("RISCO");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Add logcat please.

Answer (score 1):

Move the lines

```
        double bNow = Double.parseDouble(pegaBNow);
        double lDes = Double.parseDouble(pegaLucro);
```

To final else part (which works after checking string empty conditions)

You are **`trying to get double value before checking`** whether the string is empty or not.

If it is empty, then `parseDouble()` will throw **`NumberFormatException`** which is the reason for app crash.

Comment: You wasn't giving any explanations, just "do that", i retracted it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a "for" loop.

```
private boolean validate(EditText[] fields){
    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        EditText edtTxtName= fields[i];
        if(edtTxtName.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and use the method like this:

```
boolean checkField= validate(new EditText[] { campoBNow, campoLucro })
```

will return true if all fields are non empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app crashes because the parseDouble() can't parse an empty statement (if nothing is in the textbox). You will see it in Debug-Mode.

Check value in the Textbox before parseDouble():

```
if (pegaBNow <= 0 or pegaLucro <= 0) {
   'Emtpy Text -> do sth. but no Parse
} else {
   double bNow = parseDouble(pegaBNow);
   double lDes = parseDouble(pegaLucro);
}
```

Additionally check also if the user puts a valid Number.

Answer (score -1):

`TextUtils.isEmpty(variable_name)` should work, if app still crashes you can use debug to know why and where it is crashing.